# swiping on react-native-snap-carousel is not working as expected

Tags: react-native, react-native-snap-carousel

I am trying to use react-native-snap-carousel but however, the swiping effect is not working as expected - it is often difficult to swipe left and right, it requires user to swipe harder to move to another picture (as illustrated in the link below).

[Swiping issue with React Native Snap Carousel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ia1r9.gif)

I am not able to find any documented soluton but I found one possible prop - swipeThreshold. I try various value, but still the issue persist.

Does anyone know the solution to this?

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you to use **react-native-image-slider**.

it's flexible and easy to use.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-image-slider
I made a component named **slider.js**:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  View,
  StyleSheet,
  Image,

} from 'react-native';
import ImageSlider from 'react-native-image-slider';
export default class Slider extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <ImageSlider
        loop
        autoPlayWithInterval={3000}
        images={this.props.dataSource}
        customSlide={({ index, item, style, width }) => (
          <View key={index} style={[style, styles.customSlide]}>
            <Image source={{ uri: item }} style={styles.customImage} />
          </View>
        )}
      />
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  customImage: {
    height: 180,
    marginRight: 20,
    marginLeft: 20,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderRadius: 10,
    marginTop: 8,
  },
  customSlide: {
    backgroundColor: '#eee',
  },
});
```

you can add this to your project and use it wherever you need it like this:

```
import Slider from '../component/slider';
export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

this.state = {
  images: [
    'https://placeimg.com/640/480/nature',
    'https://placeimg.com/640/480/tech',
    'https://placeimg.com/640/480/animals',
    'https://placeimg.com/640/480/tech',
  ],
}


 render() {
    return (
    <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#eee'}}>
                <Slider dataSource={this.state.images} />
              </View>
);
}
}
```